# Does for loop on a file content keeps the file opened until the for loop completes?

Tags: for-loop, awk

My requirement is for every iteration of for loop, to write to a file which is referred in the for loop:

For Eg:

```
# cat test
1
2
3
4
5
6
# j=7; for i in `cat test`; do echo $j >> test; j=$(($j+1)); done
# cat test
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

I see it works. But I want to know if there are any dangers in it. For suppose, if I try to use awk to write to it same file, it won't work:

```
# awk '{print $1+1'} test > test
# cat test
# awk '{print $1+1'} test >> test
# cat test
```

So, when we use for loop, does the it takes all contents of file in the memory and hence, it won't cause any issue?

**Update:**

I only know `strace` command and only a little bit for debugging. With it I could see, it seems it uses memory:

```
read(255, "#!/bin/bash\nj=7; for i in `cat t"..., 76) = 76
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f96dad589d0) = 17888
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x43f2b0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x332f832660}, {0x43f2b0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x332f832660}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n", 128)      = 12
```

Comment: What is your expected output and input?

Comment: Input is any file and output is the something written to that file. It does work in for loop. But I need confirmation.

Comment: What is your question here? You want a similar logic in `awk`?

Comment: @Inian No. I just want to make sure if it good idea to write to same file in for loop. I just gave an example of how it works in awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fully expand the current contents of the file at the point where you have `` `cat test` ``. This is why you can write to the same file without affecting the loop – the loop does not keep reading from the file, and the (original) contents are indeed in memory already.

Comment: If you had read the contents of the `test` file **line by line** instead of **dumping it** ( like for example, `j=7; while read; do echo $j >> test; (( j++ )); done < test`), the behaviour would be **very different**.

Comment: Thanks..Yes, that makes sense! I also however, this is bad practice to parse text in this way using cat command. That's any how is different question.

Comment: @Jdamian lol...it's causing infinite loop as the file keeps on increasing. So, in this case, the correct way is indeed using `cat test`.

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik, yes, that is why I have highlighted "**very different**" in my comment.

Comment: @Jdamian I don't understand how it works. So, when while reads a line in the file, it goes to that line position and for appending to the file, it again goes to the end position? So how does awk work? Why can't it work like 'While'?

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik Any solution where you read the file incrementally during the loop (such as `while read` and `awk`) doesn't know that it should stop at the original end of the file, so it will just keep reading the new stuff you added to the end of the file during the loop. Theoretically you could first obtain the length of the file and terminate the loop when you reach the original end position, but a much simpler solution is to write the output to a different file (perhaps appending it to the original at the end).